# Programatically changing the background of an ExpandableListView's group during onResume in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-drawable, onresume

I've been having some trouble with onPause and onResume when implementing an ExpandableListView in my app. I may be doing this all wrong (in which case please tell me and I will endeavor to do it correctly) as I'm learning Android mainly from what I can find on the net. So, to jump into it, I've pretty much got my ExpandableListView working as I would like, but for one little bugbear. When I resume the activity (for example after the screen shuts off) I recreate my cursors (is that the best way to resume the activity? I was getting cursor errors before...) and then programatically expand the groups that were expanded when the activity was paused. Now ALL I want to do is change the background drawable for the expanded groups, but I can't seem to find a way to get their views. Any ideas?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String searchText = ((QueryString)this.getApplicationContext()).getQuery();
    if((searchText == null || searchText.length() < 1))
        if(!hasQuery)
            refreshCursor();
        else
            searchCursor(queryString);
    else
        searchCursor(searchText);

    ArrayList<Integer> ToExpand = (ArrayList<Integer>) ExpandedList.clone();
    ExpandedList.clear();
    for(Integer i : ToExpand)
    {
        listContent.expandGroup(i);
        listContent.getChildAt(i).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.listview_style_selected));        //NOT WORKING
    }
}
```

EDIT:

What I really want is the View that I have just expanded programatically with `listContent.expandGroup(i)` so that I can then change the background drawable manually. Unfortunately `getGroupView` (where the background is normally changed) doesn't fire when you expand a group programatically so the background drawable remains unchanged. How can I get this view?

Answer (score 0):

Call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) in your adapter of your list. This should work. Maybe logging the "getChildAt" view helps.

Comment: No luck with notifyDataSetChanged(). I'll try logging the getChildAt when I'm back from work this evening.

Comment: getChildAt returns null... not sure that's the right function to be using.